# Are there any .NET/CIL languages that support user-defined default constructors for value types?

Tags: .net, default-constructor, value-type

Is there a .NET/CIL language that supports user-defined default constructors for value types? I know that they were planning that feature for C# 6/VB 14, but it looks like it was dropped.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It seems like a perfectly valid question.

Comment: No.  It is a complete lead balloon.  Sounds good on paper, once you start digging in to see what the CLS spec can provide that it gets very, very ugly in a hurry.  It only works if you only use *one* language so the compiler can provide the guarantee that there won't be any ambiguity between the unavoidable "everything zero" constructor and the custom default constructor.  The F# guys get away with stuff like that.  Not the C# way.

Comment: @HansPassant — Actually, I did try both F# and C++/CLI before posting, and neither one of those support that feature. Also,I know why the Visual Studio languages will likely never support it. I was just hoping there was some exotic language (e.g. Nemerle) that had offered what I wanted.